# Google Play Game Service, automatching player information not included in result data

Tags: android, google-play-games

I made a simple example game app using google play game service by following google sample.

In the code, I started player selection screen by using `GameClient.getSelectPayersIntent()` method just like sample.

```
 intent = getGamesClient().getSelectPlayersIntent(1, 3);
 showScreen(Screen.WAITING);
 startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
```

Player selection activity returned result data, but it does not include `GamesClient.EXTRA_PLAYERS`, `GamesClient.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS`, `GamesClient.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS` extras even though I chose two auto match players.

When I debugged it, it only holds `com.google.android.gms.games.MAX_SELECTION` , `com.google.android.gms.games.MIN_SELECTION` extras in its extra map.

In the javadoc for [getSelectPlayersIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#getSelectPlayersIntent%28int,%20int%29%20javadoc), result should include chosen player information.

Do I need to do some setup for this feature working?

Here is my `onActivityResult` code. I just copied it from sample.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SELECT_PLAYERS:
            // we got the result from the "select players" UI -- ready to create the room
            handleSelectPlayersResult(responseCode, intent);
            break;
        case RC_INVITATION_INBOX:
            // we got the result from the "select invitation" UI (invitation inbox). We're
            // ready to accept the selected invitation:
            handleInvitationInboxResult(responseCode, intent);
            break;
        ... other stuffs


private void handleSelectPlayersResult(int response, Intent data) {
    if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.w(TAG, "*** select players UI cancelled, " + response);
        showScreen(Screen.MAIN);
        return;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Select players UI succeeded.");

    // get the invitee list
    final ArrayList<String> invitees = data.getStringArrayListExtra(GamesClient.EXTRA_PLAYERS);
    if (invitees != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Invitee count: " + invitees.size());
    }

    // get the automatch criteria
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
    int minAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(GamesClient.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
    int maxAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(GamesClient.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
    if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0 || maxAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
        autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
        Log.d(TAG, "Automatch criteria: " + autoMatchCriteria);
    }

    // create the room
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating room...");
    RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    if (invitees != null) {
        rtmConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
    }
    rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
        rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    }
    showScreen(Screen.WAITING);
    keepScreenOn();
    getGamesClient().createRoom(rtmConfigBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "Room created, waiting for it to be ready...");
}
```

## Update

Oops, it was my fault. I used sent intent, not received data Intent.

Comment: Just checked, I also followed along with this code sample, and I'm getting the minAutoMatchPlayers and maxAutoMatchPlayers being returned.  I wouldn't think your setup would have anything in play, as the information is returned in the intent.  Per chance, are you on Rev 11?

Comment: @user2346305 thank you for comment. I'm using latest version, Rev 12.

Comment: Very strange, I can't even find MIN_SELECTION or MAX_SELECTION in the api reference...  And your  call to start the selection process was copy/paste as well?    Intent intent = mHelper.getGamesClient().getSelectPlayersIntent(1, 3);
         startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);

Comment: @user2346305 yes, I started activity by example code
    intent = getGamesClient().getSelectPlayersIntent(1, 3);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);

I didn't find MIN_SELECTION or MAX_SELECTION in the api reference, too. I found these values through debugger. They are included in result intent of selection activity.